# Prevent duplication of records in oracle

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to know the way, where we have to prevent the duplication of records in a table in which no primary constraint existed.

SCENARIO:

Two database in existence, 
one is centralised
Another is in domain used as production for live project.

Our project is used for salary disbursement. In order to do this, third party organisation pushed employee salary data in centralised database.

We migrate the same in our database, you can think as an exact replica.
after migration we verify the records on both side.

If 2000 records pushed by third party then exactly 2000 records should be present at our side too.

The problem is there is no concept of primary key either in centralised side or in our side.

The format of data is shown as below

```
SALARY_REPORT_ID    EMP_NAME    EMP_CODE    PAY_CODE    PAY_CODE_NAME   AMOUNT  PAY_MODE    PAY_CODE_DESC   YYYYMM  REMARK  EMP_ID  PRAN_NUMBER PF_NUMBER   PRAN_NO ATTOFF_EMPCODE  REFERENCE_ID
13488158    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    104     7427    1   HOUSE RENT ALLOW    201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
13488159    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    100     23885   3   BASIC PAY   201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
13488160    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    103     9590    1   DEARNESS ALLOW. 201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
13488161    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    100     191800  1   BASIC PAY   201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
13488162    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    303     40000   2   PF SUB-PAY(GPF) 201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
13488163    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    502     20  2   G.T.I.S.    201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
13488164    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    503     72  2   SCLIS   201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
13488165    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    999     69441   1   NET EARNING 201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
13488166    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    998     195692  2   GROSS DEDUCTION 201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
13488167    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    997     265133  1   GROSS EARNING   201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
13488168    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    134     16006   3   WAGE REVISION ARREARS   201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
13488169    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    108     400 1   CONVEYANCE ALLOWANCE    201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
13488170    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    134     16025   3   WAGE REVISION ARREARS   201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
13488171    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    506     600 2   GSLI(Board Employee)    201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
13488172    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    312     155000  2   INCOME TAX  201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
```

As shown above in data set, one employee is associated to many grade pay and amount.

Now every month we need to migrate the exact data into our database.
last month the data will be duplicated at our side.
Meaning, in third-party DB the record was 2000, after migration at our end we found it is 4000, or triple case also i,e 6000.

This will happen because there is no constraint and validation implemented in the table. i want to avoid the duplication, but we can't able to use primary key, because each employee associated to many grade pay.

I was suggested to create unique index by combining two or more column, but after tried this I got an error

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SDR ON SALARY_DETAIL_REPORT_042018(EMP_CODE,PAY_CODE);

Error starting at line : 11 in command -
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SDR ON SALARY_DETAIL_REPORT_042018(EMP_CODE,PAY_CODE)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01452: cannot CREATE UNIQUE INDEX; duplicate keys found
01452. 00000 -  "cannot CREATE UNIQUE INDEX; duplicate keys found"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

How do i create the unique index for this table?

Comment: I don't quite understand why you can't create a primary key. How about a unique index, then? Preferrably on SALARY_REPORT_ID, possibly on combination of [EMP_COE, PAY_CODE, YYYYMM].

Comment: How do I create unique index or super key?

Comment: See if SALARY_REPORT_ID be primary key, then it is not enough to resist the duplication, if I specify the constraint on EMP_CODE, then only single record will be inserted

Comment: That's why I suggested combination of several columns. Syntax is `create unique index ui_sal on your_table (emp_code, pay_code, yyyymm)`

Comment: ohkk thanks, can I do the same via SQL developer

Comment: Yes, you can, no problem.

Comment: ohhkk..Can you tell me the pros of this and ya, is there any cons of this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  select the table you want on the navigator and right click, selecting indexes > Create Index

When this dialog appears, you can create your multicolumn unique index.
[image]
You can also see the DDL you would write as well.
[image]

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-01452: cannot CREATE UNIQUE INDEX; duplicate keys found
01452. 00000 -  "cannot CREATE UNIQUE INDEX; duplicate keys found"

Comment: can non-unique index avoids the duplication of records

Comment: no, it cant.  To avoid duplication managed by the database, you'll need to decide which combination of columns will make up your unique key. You can choose as many columns as you need to identify a unique row